# ask for password when wanting to reboot or shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, teamviewer, remote-shutdown

I want my PC to ask me for a password when it tries to reboot or restart. My friend thought it was funny to use remote control on teamviewer to restart my PC, and knowing him, hes definitely going to try that again next time I get on teamviewer with him. I'd like to prevent him from doing so. How?

Comment: These are the details of the processes that take place when any software needs to request the OS to shutdown; http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html ; Not exactly a solution to your problem but I'm hoping this will give some idea about how to proceed next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as TeamViewer often run under Administrative privileges. And I have used TeamViewer for quite a while, and the TeamViewer bar has its own Shutdown button, which I believe basically send some commands directly to the OS.

The only thing you might be able to do is to set up TeamViewer to "confirm" everything the person connecting do.

To do this you go under Options - Advanced - Advanced Settings for Connections to this computer.

Access Control -> Custom Settings

```
Under "Control this Computer" might want to change it "After Confirmation" -
```

He can't control unless you give confirmation. He can only connect and view your screen.

and

```
Lock the local keyboard and mouse "Denied" - so he can't lock you out
```

and

```
Control the local TeamViewer "Denied" - so he can't change that setting.
```

Hopefully that helps. (I haven't personally tested it, but those are the relevant options that I can think of)

Darius

Comment: Unfortunately you're probably right about it being impossible. :\ Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the shutdown/restart options entirely through local GPO:
http://scorpiotek.com/blog/?p=626
Then the options aren't even available. If you really need to shutdown, just issue the "shutdown" command from the command prompt.(though you friend may figure this out as well)

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true

If it's a true window prompt your after, I'd suggest looking at a vbscript that fires when you logoff. Though I'm not entirely sure if you can cancel a shutdown/restart from a script.

Comment: Theres an option in teamviewer that is under the action tab called "shutdown", so he is not even using the windows taskbar menu unfortunately.

Comment: ah, I am unfamiliar with the software so I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Click on Start → Run… → **gpedit.msc** (or, alternatively: WinR → gpedit.msc)
- Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System
- Display Shutdown Event Tracker → Enable

*This is not available in all editions, though, so you could also try:*

- Click on Start → Run… → regedit (or, alternatively: WinR → regedit)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability
- New → DWORD 32
- Enter as name: ShutdownReasonUI
- Enter as value: 1

https://superuser.com/a/433920/219655

Comment: I wasn't sure what the shutdown event tracker was, so I tested it and its that window you get when your PC gets back on after you shut it down, asking you why it was shut down. I need something that prevents the computer from terminating. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be just unistall team viewer or if you actually use it on a regular basis remove him as user or change your password